# torque of locked gear motor vs gearless motor

Tags: motor

Do gears increase the torque of locked/stalled motor ?. I understand that in case of rotation of shaft the gears will increase the torque because of transmission to slow rpm. But what makes difference in case of stalled/locked shaft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reducing gear box can be modeled as a lever: the small force of the stalled motor is multiplied by the reduction factor, to appear as a much larger force at the output shaft.

[image]